# GameRanger interface not usable in Wine 1.6

Tags: windows, wine

I recently moved from a Windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.04, and I play Warcraft III a lot with my friends using GameRanger. So I moved my WC3 to the Wine disk and managed to install GameRanger (after a whole day fighting with winetricks for mfc42.dll). Although some people report not being able to login, it worked perfectly for me. However, when the game and friends list shows up, I am not able to click on anything (in fact, the windows even go out of focus). I can press alt to bring up the toolbar menus, but I cant navigate with keyboard nor mouse. Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Well, my solution was simple but overkill: I copied my whole Windows installation over to wine's virtual drive, and it worked.